# Error while launching Wakfu

Tags: java

I installed Wakfu on my Ubuntu 12.04 from the source downloaded from the game website. While installing I got an error:

```
'/home/sony/Downloads/Wakfu_unix.sh' 
Unpacking JRE ...
Preparing JRE ...
Starting Installer ...
Could not display the GUI. This application needs access to an X Server.
*******************************************************************
You can also run this application in console mode without
access to an X server by passing the argument -c
*******************************************************************
```

I used `'/home/sony/Downloads/Wakfu_unix.sh' -c` to install it.
But while opening it the following error came up:

```
 '/opt/ankama/Wakfu/Wakfu' 
The archive /opt/ankama/Wakfu/core.jar does not exist.
```

I also installed sun java. What should I do?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might have run into a 64 vs 32 bit problem. In this [thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1939715) they seem to solve the issue.